# i got stuck with my standalone hibernate project i am getting this error pls help me

Tags: java, hibernate

I got stuck with my standalone hibernate project. I am getting this error

```
Nov 10, 2015 4:24:55 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration configure
INFO: HHH000043: Configuring from resource: /hibernate.cfg.xml
Nov 10, 2015 4:24:55 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration getConfigurationInputStream
INFO: HHH000040: Configuration resource: /hibernate.cfg.xml
Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.HibernateException: /hibernate.cfg.xml not found
```

Answer (score 1):

The exception says it all, it can't find the hibernate.cfg.xml file.  That file needs to be in the classpath somewhere.